# Module not Found: Can't resolve Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Trying to run npm dev and unable to locate file context.js

Using this to call the context

`import { AccountContext } from '../context.js'`

And this is my context.js file

`import { createContext } from 'react' export const AccountContext = createContext(null)`

Is there an installation I'm missing?

Comment: The error message means that there is no file `context.js` with relative path `../context.js`. Is the path correct?

Comment: Revised the path and was indeed incorrect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you are exporting a single context (at the end its a function) per file, you can do `default` export & import. Like this-

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
const AccountContext = createContext(null)
export default AccountContext
```

import it like this-

```
import AccountContext from '../context.js'
```

You may want to refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#examples) doc to see best practices of importing and exporting modules.